# How to use the WP export and get images that are contained in a posts gallery

Tags: gallery, export

I ran the standard wp Export on a single custom post type called products.  I got all the custom fields and all that but each cpt has a standard post gallery. The link to the image is not coming through the export. I need the imported products to have the same post gallery that the old site did.  I also don't want to manually re-add them as there are quite a few.

Is there a way to export that custom post type, and pull the images over as well?  I am fine with having to manually move the images via ftp but I openned the exported xml and there is no notation of the images linked to this custom post type.

I am using 3.4